# Multiple sitefeeds on one site

Tags: newsfeed, sitefeed

Is it possible to have 2 individual sitefeeds on the same site?

I'd like to add a sitefeed to a seperate page which doesn't include content from the primary sitefeed.
By default, SharePoint mirrors sitefeed content on every sitefeed within the same site.

My current workaround has been to use a pageviewer webpart to display the sitefeed from a subsite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment above, I "solved" this by embedding a subsite's newsfeed onto a page on the parent site. I hid the ribbon with CSS beforehand.